# Writing command prompt to a file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I started cmd and using some commands I started some services which eventually starts a new cmd window and it shows some logs in that window and closed within seconds. I want it redirect to a file. I have tried as below

```
  command > D:\temp.txt
```

But it is of no use...can any one tell me how

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
command > D:\temp.txt 2>&1
```

But your command itself works fine. Update your question with command to get the clear answer.